# Contact Form not sending e-mail

Tags: php

After reading all the other articles about this issue it does not help mine. I have created a contact form the html is fine, I think there is something missing in the php, I need it after it submits to display a "Your E-mail has been sent successfully message. Also, the e-mail that I receive after submittal doesn't display the information posted and not sure how to get it to do that.

```
/* Logic Script */
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$first_nameErr = $emailErr = $last_nameErr = $commentsErr = "";
$first_name = $last_name = $email = $comments = "";

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["first_name"])) {
    $first_nameErr = "First Name is required";
        } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }


if (empty($_POST["last_name"])) {
    $last_nameErr = "Last Name is required";
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name)) {
      $last_nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comments"])) {
    $comments = "";
  } else {
    $comments = test_input($_POST["comments"]);
  }
}

//Code for sending the e-mail//
$email = $_POST["email"]; 
$to = "jason.cameron@myaolcollege.com";
$subject = "Canada Algae E-mail Contact";
$headers = "From: $email\n"; 

$message = "A visitor to your site has sent the following email address to be added to your mailing list.\n

Email Address: $email
Name: $first_name $last_name
Comments: $comments";



print("Your form was submitted successfully");

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
?>
```

The html:

```
/* display code */
<div class="border"></div>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <header class="nav">
            <img src="images/CA_Logo.png" alt="Canada Algae Logo">
            <a href="#" class="flt_r">
                Contact Us
            </a>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div id="main"> 
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post" id="contact_form">

            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name">
                <span class="error"> <?php echo $first_nameErr;?> </span>
                <br />

            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name">
                <span class="error"> <?php echo $last_nameErr;?> </span>
                <br />

            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                <input type="text" name="email">

                <span class="error"> 
                    <?php echo $emailErr;?>
                </span>
                <br />

            <label for="comments">Comments</label>

            <textarea name="comments">Type your comments here</textarea> 

            <input type="submit" value="submit">     
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>Contact Us!</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<div class="border"></div>

</html>
```

It is all on one file.

Comment: Is that PHP code included on the same page as the HTML form? The form is set to redirect to itself with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], so if they are they are two different files none of the PHP will execute.

Comment: it is on the same page yes

Comment: There's hardly ever a reason to use `stripslashes`, especially on input like this. Magic Quotes was killed off years ago.

Comment: That is interesting to know I wonder why W3C would include it? just thinking out loud

Comment: W3C doesn't have anything to do with PHP. Are you talking about w3schools? They, in turn, have nothing to do with W3C.

Comment: well that answers that question, but not my original question :) and yes it is w3c schools if this is out of date then a link to a tutorial would be great even. Otherwise what is missing to make this a complete program would be good to

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP - you have

```
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
```

but in your html that input is called  first_name.

You need to change the PHP to :

```
$name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
```

also - are you actually showing the name and comment from the form post - it seems like you are only using the email address.

Comment: Hi Gavgrif - just a quick note to say that we prefer posts unsigned here. We tend to think of the profile block as the sig, and that it doesn't need repeating. Thanks!